# How to remove hidden characters from text string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, string-matching

I am having difficulty to match two text strings. One contains some hidden characters from a text string.

I have a text string: "PR & Communications" stored on an SQL database. When pulled from there, into `$database_version`, `var_dump($database_version)` reveals the string to have 19 bytes.

I have scraped (with permission) from a website, some text into a variable, `$web_version`. Ostensibly the string is "PR & Communications" but it does not match the database version, i.e `if($database_version == $web_version)` is NOT true.

`var_dump()` reveals `$web_version` to have 23 bytes. `trim()` has no effect, nor does `strip_tags()` but `preg_replace( '/[^\PC\s]/u', $web_version )` removes something because afterwards `string_var($web_version)` reveals the string to comprise 14 bytes only. It has clearly removed something, possibly too much, as the string still does not match with `$database_version`.

Any ideas how to:

1. find out what has been removed
2. strip out just enough to match $database_version?

PS I don't know how to view the variable in hexadecimal code

Comment: Wen your trying to compare _if( $database_version == $web_version )_ is both variable are coming in string format ? Try with some typecasting and trim method.

Comment: You can try using `utf8-decode($web_version)` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php.

Comment: debugging: to see the string as hex bytes then use `var_dump($web_version, bin2hex($web_version), __FILE__.__LINE__);`. To see what the character represent then: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) and [Complete Character List for UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Comment: Thank you Ryan, your var_dump formula revealed that one value had the '&' as an ampersand and the other as &amp;, hence the two values did not match. This helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
$v = preg_replace('/\s+|[[:^print:]]/', '', $string);
```

trim() removes only " \t\n\r\0\x0B" (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)), so use snippet above to remove non-printed characters from string.

Comment: this helped me resolve a slightly different issue. Perhaps you could clarify on non printed characters and what this regex actually does?

Comment: `[[:print:]]` is PCRE print character class (alias for complex regex, more of them: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) syntax. Print character means visible on page render. `^` symbol inside character class or group means negation, so `[[:^print:]]` means non-printable character - ones that are not visible after page render (like BOM-mark, for example). Other parts of regex is very easy - `\s` stands for "any space symbols", (space, tab, new line ,etc.), `+` means "repeat one or more times", pipe (`|`) means "or".

Comment: So, as whole, it could be read as "find any space symbol or non-printable character".